# How to calculate percentiles in a triangle

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, percentile

i have this PDF function and i am tasked with finding the 20th percentile of X for Y = 2 where X is a random variable [image]

I tried calculating the area of the triangle for x=0.25 and it resulted in the 25th percentile but i'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: So the answer you want is less than $0.25$.  You can use similar triangles to find the value

Comment: Can you please elaborate further ?

Comment: Find the value x on the horizontal axis for which a vertical line at x cuts 20% of the area under the triangle from the lower side of the triangle. It seems that x = .25 is the answer for 25%. // To start, what is the value of Y that makes the area under the triangle equal to $1?$ Then what is the equation of the line that makes the left-hand boundary of the triangle.

Comment: Find the cdf for $0\leq{x}\leq{0.25}$ which is $F(x)=4x^2$, then solve the equation $F(x)=0.2$, the solution will be the percentile you're looking for.